# How to animate div twice in the success function?

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is the current AJAX code that I am using:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'action.php',
            success: function () {
              $(".success").show().delay(300).fadeOut();
              $(".success").show().delay(600).fadeOut();
            }

          });
```

What happens here is that the div 'success' gets shown for a few seconds (as it is currently set with a 'display: none' property) when the AJAX call is a success. This code works but how would I make it so that it gets called twice? So the div gets shown for a few seconds, then after about a second it gets shown again for another few seconds?

Comment: So right now they both show up at the same time and 1 disappear before the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this -

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".success").show().delay(300).fadeOut().delay(300).fadeIn().delay(300).fadeOut();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="success" style="display:none;">Test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'action.php',
            success: function () {
              $(".success").show().delay(300).fadeOut().delay(100).show().delay(600).fadeOut();
            }

          });
```